# Codeigniter 404 Error On Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

i changed my controller name from controller.php to Controller.php
also changed my base_url in config file to the directory where my website is hosted like www.abc.com/websitefolder
but still i am getting 404 error 
website url : www.cyfers.com/moving/

my base_url : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.cyfers.com/moving/';`

my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your code, routes, base url and hosted link too

Comment: hosted like is http://cyfers.com/moving/

Comment: Please supply us with more info. This is like saying " I have a problem with my car. What is it?"

Comment: @Abdulla
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.cyfers.com/moving/';

Comment: what is your main controller name ??

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i have edited the question and also mention that my every controller file is start with capital letter

Comment: @Abdulla Dashboard

$route['default_controller'] = "Dashboard";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Base URL should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://cyfers.com/moving/';
```

**In htaccss**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Your Controller file should be `dashboard.php`.

And default controller should be `$route['default_controller'] = "dashboard";`

---

To hide errors on site in root there is file call `index.php`

Change this to

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

this

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Comment: yes its already there .. i mentioned in my edited answer .. still same issue

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: change your base url and upload project

Comment: i changed .. but still same

Comment: Now add my htaccess too

Comment: shoe me `Dashboard` file name and class name

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
its also there .. i have to remove index.php ?

Comment: ya remove it and try

Comment: i have added the picture of dashbaord class with filename with my question

Comment: removed index.php from $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
still same issue

Comment: Your file name should be simple and inside its caps

Comment: so what should me the filename like ?

Comment: Check my answer. I have added that

Comment: Now its working. Check your DB setting its wrong. Once you cofigure that your site will appear.

Comment: i changed .. some model issue its mentioning

Comment: @adeelpervaiz now your sites look perfect ;)

Comment: @adeelpervaiz **make sure all your project `Dashboard` should changed to `dashboard`**